# How to calculate the probability of a die with a wild side?

Tags: probability, dice

So I have a 6-sided die with 5 different values in 5 of their sides. Its sixth side can be treated as any of the other 5 values.

So my question revolves around which is the probability of getting any of the 5 values in the die? It can't be $\frac{1}{6}$, given one of their sides can add up to that probability. Also, it can't be $\frac{1}{3}$, because then it wouldn't add up to $1$.

So, what is the real probability of each value in this die?

Comment: The probability of any number is 1/3, since that side can be read as being all five values at once, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming that any one of the other 5 sides is equiprobable on the joker face**, logically, it has to be $\frac{1}{5}$ since each side has an equal probability of being landed on, or picked on the wild face.

Now for the math. For any given fixed side, it has probability $\frac{1}{6}$ of being landed on, and $\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{30}$ of being picked, assuming that the choice of fixed face is independent (and equiprobable) from landing on the joker face. Now:
$$
\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{30} = \frac{5}{30} + \frac{1}{30} = \frac{6}{30} = \frac{1}{5}
$$

Comment: That's what I needed, just a question: Why do you add the value of being landed and of being picked? Are they independent events?

Comment: @Rono No, they are certainly not independent; they are mutually exclusive! I can add them because there is no intersection in which to worry about inclusion-exclusion. The independence of landing on the wild side and picking allows for that multiplication. But you cannot land on a face AND on the wild side (at least in three spatial dimensions).

Comment: You're right, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it would be that the number you want has a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of coming up and the other $4$ numbers each have a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance.  That is, if there is a preferred number.

Comment: That would make sense, but I'd need to know the probability independent of this information.

Comment: Then in that case, if no value has any advantage over the others, and the wild roll has equal chance of being any of the values, all 5 are 1/5.